# How do I write $\sin(2)$ as an expansion of spherical harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

I've been given a wave function, $\psi = f(r)\sin(2)$, and told to rewrite it as a summation of spherical harmonics. All of the spherical harmonics seem to be written with a $\theta$ dependence so I'm unsure of how to proceed getting this into spherical harmonics beyond writing $\sin(2)$ as $2(\sin()\cos())$.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the integral $\langle Y_l^m, \psi \rangle$ (double integral over both $\theta$ and $\phi$)?

Comment: How can I do that without first having it in terms of $Y_{l}^{m}$? I guess what I'm saying is, how can I calculate an integral of something that I don't have yet?

Comment: You have $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=f(r)\sin(2\phi)$ and $Y_l^m (\theta, \phi ) = N_{lm} e^{i m \phi } P_l^m (\cos{\theta} )$.